# Money-Rails - Simple Form Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

I'm using the money-rails gem for one of my Models to store the cost of manufacture.

In my model I have -

```
monetize :cost_of_manufacturing_cents
```

And in the _form.html view I have for simple_form :

```
f.input :cost_of_manufacturing
```

However, when I run the item/new route, I get the following error

```
undefined method `cost_of_manufacturing' for #<Item:0x007fe34a5feaf8>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Obvious stuff but, did you run the migration and restart the server? Does it work in the console, if you run rails s, then i = Item.new, i.cost_of_manufacturing ??

Comment: I did. When I run i.cost_of_manufacturing, I get this error NoMethodError: undefined method `cost_of_manufacturing' for #<Item:0x007fbddaf7c638>

Comment: I think I got the problem, there was an issue with my initializer file. Thanks for taking the time!